# Setting noise GIFs as background

Tags: html, css

Good day.
I want to set a background with gifs on the site.
The problem is that the gif itself has a white background and therefore the entire site becomes the same white.
Is there some way to eliminate this white background.
The problem is that it overlays on top of everything except the header, which has a z-index of 10. Although I set for a background with noise z-index: -1

html

```
<div class="noise-bg"></div>
```

I use a div and size it to the full width of the screen and also give it position: fixed

css

```
.noise-bg
    position: fixed
    width: 200%
    height: 200%
    top: -50%
    left: -50%
    background: url('../images/general/noise.gif')
    background-size: 1.8%
    pointer-events: none
    z-index: -1
    opacity: 16%
```

GIF [image]

Comment: If the _noise.gif_ file is not generated, you may want to look into image manipulation programs like _FFMpeg_ or _ImageMagick_ ...

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the class to the html tag:

```html
<html class="noise-bg">
```

And the CSS something like:

```css
.noise-bg {
  background: white url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzzC1.gif") left top/1.8% 1.8% repeat;
}
```

Or style directly the html tag:

```css
html {
  background: white url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzzC1.gif") left top/1.8% 1.8% repeat;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for such a long delay.
Did everything as you said. But the problem is that my background lightens a lot. I set it to # 000, but due to the noise of the hyphae, it becomes much lighter. Is there a solution to this problem at all?